# What is the correct sampler state to fit a texture to my polygons?

Tags: direct3d, hlsl

I have a "line" shader which draws lines using two triangles (bisect the line).  That all works.  Today I thought I'd draw star trails and add a texture to it:

[image]

My problem, however, is that they render like this:

[image]

So they do not appear to get "shrunk" to fit the size of the polygon, it's more like I'm getting a slice out of it.

I've tried a variety of sampler states to no avail.  The texture coords look right in the graphics debugger, and the pixel shader is a one-line sample call.

Can someone explain what's the right way to fit the texture to the poly?  I'm on DX11, though the concept is broader I suppose.

Comment: That looks somewhat correct to me in the event that you're adding the texture rather than multiplying it. I see the gradient here, but blending and how you compute the pixel color in general are probably to blame. Can you include the blend setup and relevant HLSL?

Comment: I think the mipmapping is causing your artifacts. You texture probably has a high resolution and is mapped on small quads. This leads the renderer to choose a low resolution mipmap, which is (if you don't created it yourself) a "blurred" version of your texture, which introduces the sharp edges. So I suppose to either reduce you initial texture resolution (just for testing, if it's the issue) or create your own mipmaps (e.g. predrawn in a .dds file) or disable mipmapping (will lead to oversampling).

Comment: You might want to see if turning on anisotropic filtering (D3D11_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC) solves the problem.

Comment: I believe it to be the mipmapping myself; if you want to propose that as the answer, I will accept it.